# Sum of total AgentWork Capacity differs from WorkLoad shown in Omni Supervisor

Tags: omnichannel, agentwork

Omni-channel Supervisor shows a number in "Workload" column that differs from the total AgentWork Capacity for the same user.
How is this Workload filed calculated? I guess it must consider some filter to aggregate results from AgentWork object. But I didn't find this definition in any documentation, and users are complaining about it.

One example:
User1 har a WorkLoad of 33/30 in Omni Supervisor:
[image]

If I query: `SELECT CapacityModel,  CapacityWeight, IsOwnerChangeInitiated, IsStatusChangeInitiated, OwnerId,  UserId, CreatedById, Status, WorkItem.CaseNumber FROM AgentWork WHERE Status IN ('Opened') AND UserId = '0054T000001mAWaQAM'`
It returns 84 records, all of them with CapacityWeight = 1.0

[image]

So my question is: how is the WorkLoad defined in Omni Supervisor? intuitively, I expected it to be the sum of opened AgentWork CapacityWeight for specific User, but that is not what I can observe. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Try to filter by OwnerId too. I've seen scenarios where the WorkItemId changes its ownership (by manual or automatic intervention) and moves to another user.